# How to use matRipple (directive) in ionic app?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-material

https://material.angular.io/components/ripple/examples
So, I have Ionic app

```
<ion-app>
  <ion-content>
    <div class="container">
       there is whole content
    </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-app>
```

[I want to do like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVuk5.png)

If I use this

```
 <ion-ripple-effect></ion-ripple-effect>
```

[It will look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzu8h.png)

so, how I can add ripple on click (around of click) with defined radius?